# Best practices for handling different ajax calls in generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, ashx

I do a lot of ajax calls in my project, and my generic handlers usually en up pretty messy. Do you guys have any tips on how to manage a lot of calls in the same file? My current solution is to pass a functionname as the first parameter, and then decide on where to end up in the handler based on the name. But this doesnt feel like the best way. Any tips are much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want GET information on a resource the server knows about, or to DELETE one, or PUT a new state, then define a URI that refers to it. Querystring parameters are fine for defining just which one (e.g. `?id=34`) but not types of resource - that confuses too many separate issues.

POST handlers shouldn't handle too many different tasks. Ideally one, though maybe stretching to a few more if they are *very* similar in their operation.

In other words, Ajax brings nothing new, behind the scenes it's the same web built on HTTP that we had in the 90s. Ajax is just a new way to deal with that.

Comment: "POST handlers should handle" = "Should'nt"? :) I know that AJAX doesnt bring anything "new", its still the same stuff being done back-end. Ive just been using GET and POST so far.

Comment: Yes, shouldn't. My point isn't that the fact that it's the same old web is earth-shattering, so much as to consider it the same way you would if it was being used in a browser or `HTTPWebRequest`. Identify your resources, and give them URIs, rather than handling them all from the same address. You might want to patch a few different URIs into the same IHttpHandler, but start thinking of them separately and combine when it makes life easier, rather than starting with them all combined and splitting when you can't follow the mess any more.

Comment: @JonHanna Can you please illustrate this a little more for me? Are you talking about creating routes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.ASPX

Comment: @Rod that's one means of setting up the code to do what I describe above, though I normally just create an IHttpHandler or IHttpAsyncHandler and define the routes in web.config files.